# Most natural way to say "absolutely not"? 決して 絶対に?

Tags: word-choice

I would like to say:
"He never comes to Osaka (no matter what)"

彼は決して大阪に行かない。

To express the "never" part, I know there are words like 決して、絶対に、全然、全く, but which sound more natural to the Japanese ear when spoken and when written? 
And are there other words to express this as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If saying "no matter what" is important, 絶対に is the most natural option in speech. Both 絶対に and 決して will work fine in written text, but the latter would sound a bit more formal. This is one of the [exceptions where a kango version sounds less formal](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/38630/5010). Other idiomatic options include:

- 彼は[頑として](http://jisho.org/word/%E9%A0%91%E3%81%A8%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6)大阪に行かない。
- 彼は何があっても大阪に行かない。
- 彼は[雨が降ろうが槍が降ろうが](http://jisho.org/word/%E9%9B%A8%E3%81%8C%E9%99%8D%E3%82%8D%E3%81%86%E3%81%8C%E6%A7%8D%E3%81%8C%E9%99%8D%E3%82%8D%E3%81%86%E3%81%8C)大阪に行こうとしない。

全然 and 全く just mean "at all", but they do not mean "no matter what." They are often used for something you can count or measure. In this context, using 全く/全然 would imply he is expected to go to Osaka on a regular basis, but don't do so *even once*.

- [全然 {ぜんぜん} with positive adjective / na-adjective](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/794/5010)
- [全く vs 全然 (formal / casual)](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/29271/5010)

Answer (score 1):

> "He never comes to Osaka (no matter what)"

どれがnaturalかは状況に応じますので明確に言えません。
以下の（　）の中に、各々に対して私の感じを書きますので参考にしてください。

1. 彼は決して大阪に行かない。（本人の意志が固い。客観的に見て行かない理由もなんとなく分かる。2より上品な/穏やかな表現）
2. 彼は絶対に大阪に行かない。（本人の意志が固い）
3. 彼は全然大阪に行かない。（客観的に見て行く気配がない）
4. 彼は全く大阪に行かない。（客観的に見て行く気配がない。3より上品な/穏やかな表現）
5. 彼は頑として大阪に行かない。(本人の意志が1,2より固い)